# ABP BoilerPlate: i cant see my exception message when i'm using UserFirendlyException

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

i'm using ABP ASP boilerplate .net core / angular client side frame work.
i want to show specific message when some condition exists in server side by raising `UserFriendlyException("myMessage")` but in client side only showing popup window 
[image: this window show "An internal error occurred during your request!"]

my end point API signature  is like this `async Task<BDto> CalcBodies(ADto input)`

Comment: Check your Logs.txt.

Comment: Check the error in Browser Console  and Logs.txt file in YourHostProject\App_Data\Logs folder

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by specifying `LocalizationSourceName` property of Service instance base on this post : [GitHub link](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/commit/62ee93ca6dec602882334b33896a9b4d3df1b283)

Comment: yeah that's a must. I thought you successfully get UserFriendlyExceptions for the rest of your project.

Comment: could i set this property in some where so that it no longer needs to be set in all descendant services without changing base service class? (like some configuration module approach)

Comment: you can create a new base controller inherited from AbpApiController. And set it in the constructor of the new base controller.